# Does anybody know the view plugin that appears on the mid-click. I remember it was a circle with some useful buttons

Tags: unity, gnome, plugins

I had this plugin 3 or 4 years ago and found it on omgubuntu. It looked like the circle panel that appears where you click. Just like the compass.

So many years past I wonder if it has support for 14.04 or 15.04.

Comment: Something of [this kind](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25002/are-circular-menu-button-interfaces-intuitive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Gnome-Pie

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:simonschneegans/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-pie
```

Start with `gnome-pie` via Dash or Activities

[image]

---

If you don't like Gnome-Pie, simply remove via

```
sudo purge-ppa ppa:simonschneegans/testing
```

Comment: A little bet late but yeah, I've started using gnome-pie